# How to save as high resolution print at a specific dimensional size with InkScape 1.2+

Tags: inkscape, print-design

I have InkScape 1.2.2 installed and I have a print preperation question.  Based on my attached screenshot...

[image]

You will see that I have a document that is 7 by 5 inches for the page size.  It has an example design in the middle. **I simply want my end product to 7 x 5 inch print at 900 DPI** (preferably .png if possible??)

- When I attempt to export, it wants me to adjust the size of the export in pixels, not inches, which is frustrating.
- When I attempt to change the DPI on export, it also changes the dimensions that its going to be.

Many thanks on what to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions of PNG images are always measured in pixels, which is why the width and height inputs use px. To get the required count of pixels for the desired DPI, you multiply the inches by the *Dots per Inch* value:

```
7in × 900dpi = 6300px
5in × 900dpi = 4500px
```

So you would enter a width of `6300px` and height of `4500px` to get the output you want.

However, the 'DPI' input does that automatically for you, using the page dimensions set in the 'Document Properties' (if the export region is set to 'Page'). So you just need to set it to `900` and it'll change the width and height accordingly.

If you uncheck the 'Hide Export Settings' box, you can also set the 'pHYs DPI' value of the output file. However that is just a hint for printers of how many inches big the final print should be.

Comment: You're awesome!  thank you so much!